Get the arguments types contained within tRPC resolver function for create t3 app
I am working on a create-t3-app@7.30.2 app - I'm new to it.
I have a postRouter like so:
export const postRouter = createTRPCRouter({
  create: protectedProcedure
    .input(createPostSchema)
    .mutation(async ({ ctx, input } /*where does this type come from? */) => {
      /* lots of logic to check if we can create a post ( uniqueness checks ) */
      return ctx.db.post.create({
        data: {
          author: {
            connect: { id: ctx.session.user.id },
          },
          content: input.content,
          excerpt: input.excerpt,
          slug,
          title: input.title,
          videoUrl: input.videoUrl,
        },
      });
    }),
  getSecretMessage: protectedProcedure.query(() => {...}),
});


I want to refactor this to
export const postRouter = createTRPCRouter({
  create: protectedProcedure
    .input(createPostSchema)
    .mutation(createPostService)
});

How exactly do I specify the create post argument types for this resolver fn?
https://trpc.io/docs/server/procedures#inferProcedureBuilderResolverOptions and https://trpc.io/docs/client/vanilla/infer-types seems to be a start, but not exactly sure the best way here.

// this is what I have come up with - but there's gotta be a better way.
type NotGreatNotTerrible = inferProcedureBuilderResolverOptions<typeof protectedProcedure> & { 
  input: inferRouterInputs<typeof postRouter>["create"];
}


export const createPostService = async ({ ctx, input }: NotGreatNotTerrible) => {
  /* lots of logic to check if we can create a post ( uniqueness checks ) */
  return ctx.db.post.create({
    data: {
      author: {
        connect: { id: ctx.session.user.id },
      },
      content: input.content,
      excerpt: input.excerpt,
      slug,
      title: input.title,
      videoUrl: input.videoUrl,
    },
  });
};


